# Website and WCF Service with same SSL certificate

Tags: wcf, ssl

I have a website and a WCF service.

They both needs to be running with a SSL certificate. The certificate is bound to my website www.example.com

Do I need to buy a second certificate for the WCF service or should I host it on the website? Or whats the best approach?

If possible I would like to host it as a Windows service.

Comment: I've just used the same certificate on the basis the web site and the service were trading "my" data so should be secured by "my" certificate. Theres no security implication in using a cert for multiple sites.

Comment: Did you host the service on the website?